# xpath: Picking tag after text

Tags: xpath

How would one, via xpath, select the `strong` tag after `baz` text for example?

```
<p>
<br>foo<strong>this foo</strong>

<br>bar<strong>this bar</strong>

<br>baz<strong>this baz</strong>

<br>qux<strong>this qux</strong></p>
```

Obviously the following does not work....

```
//p[text() = 'baz']/following-sibling::select[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
//p/text()[. = 'baz']/following-sibling::strong[1]
```

Demo here - http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/b67bad4d-4d38-4e2d-a3df-b7e5a2e9f286

This solution relies on no whitespace around your text nodes. You will need to switch to using the following if you start using indentation or other whitespace characters

```
//p/text()[normalize-space(.) = 'baz']/following-sibling::strong[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Phil!...used the normalize-space method on another example, but doesn't seem to be taking.  http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/d9217787-8c73-48c9-8558-6a63c93918a4 Any suggestions?  added a 'space' and 'colon'

Comment: kinda answered my own question with this: http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/ca13e542-c02d-4aeb-aa6f-c59d4c267b24 I removed the space.  However, the xpath engine i'm using, doesn't recognize the 'normalize-space' method.  So looks like i'm sunk anyway.  Thanks though!

Comment: @RyanSchultz Could always use `contains()` instead